# Can i call a NSThread function detachNewThreadSelector: toTarget: withObject: with 2 parameters?

Tags: iphone, nsthread

I want call a function which makes my main thread stuck using the above function so that it can run in a diff thread. But the problem is that my function have 2 parameters. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass as the object an `NSDictionary` built using all of the arguments needed by your function (can be even more than two using the dictionary).

In the code related to the function you pass as a selector, you then retrieve from the dictionary your arguments as the objects stored within the dictionary.