# NSThread, how to call a method with 2 param's

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im trying to use NSThread so my display pic can load in the background so im calling it by

```
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(displayPic:aURL :aURL2) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

But as im passing through 2 Strings, how would i construct this statement?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i call a NSThread function detachNewThreadSelector: toTarget: withObject: with 2 parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047676/can-i-call-a-nsthread-function-detachnewthreadselector-totarget-withobject-wit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple hack, use NSArray? Or use any other collection such as NSDictionary.

Example

```
NSArray *extraArgs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:string1, string2, nil];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(displayPic:) toTarget:self withObject:extraArgs];
[extraArgs release];
```

There no proper way of doing this, as far as i am aware.

Comment: So theres no easier way of doing this apart from creating an array to just strip it when i get into displaypic method?

Comment: How would i also change my method, would it be 

- (void)displayPic: (NSArray *) newarray{
//code
};

Comment: Yep, exactly that. 

Then just extract the strings out of the array as you normally would. It's annoying.

Comment: Thanks, Ill have to solve the issue i now have with passing objects and selectors. One problem leads to another one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pass an `NSDictionary` built using all of the arguments needed by your function as the parameter.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(displayPic:) toTarget:self withObject:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"http://www.example.org/a.jpg", @"aURL", @"http://www.example.org/a.jpg", @"aURL2", nil]];
```

In the function you pass as a selector's code, you then retrieve from the dictionary the arguments you stored:

```
- (void) displayPic: (NSDictionary*)args
{
   NSString *aURL = [args valueForKey: @"aURL"],
            *aURL2 = [args valueForKey: @"aURL2"];

   //The rest of the code
   //...
}
```

Comment: Just saw this, This looks a lot neater then creating arrays!

Will give this a smash

Answer (score 1):

Well:

There is a way of asynchronously calling arbitrary methods on objects that would go through `NSOperationQueue` and I would highly recommend using operation-queues over `NSThreads` most of the time.

Depending on the OS you are targeting (iPhone 3.x or iOS 4), this would be a one-liner or a lenghty chunk of code.

For iOS 4 behold the one-liner (assuming you have an `NSOperationQueue` called `queue` and your worker-object called `worker`):

```
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{ [worker displayPic:url1 :url2]; }];
```

Note that this works on OS X 10.6 as well.

The 3.x version would require you to either subclass `NSOperation` or use `NSInvocationOperation` -- which would have been what I originally wrote.

But here's the thing:

If all you want to do is prefetching something in the background, just modify your worker to only take one URL and use that with a queue to wich you add more of these fetchers.

Then the solutions becomes easy again on 2.x:

```
NSInvocationOperation *workerOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:worker selector:@selector(displayURL:) object:url];
[queue addOperation:workerOperation]; // retains the operation
[workerOperation release];
```

Hope this helps